# Cufon - multiple fonts/styles in one replacement

Tags: cufon

Another cufon question.

What I'm basically trying to do is render something like this correctly.

### This is the *best* product ever

I had assumed that cufon would replace the italics with an italic version of the font, but now it would seem that it's only intended to replace a whole block that happened to ALL be italics. Do I correctly understand that replacing a contained single word (or short phrase) with italic version, or bold etc, is out of cufon's capabilities?

To be honest, what I wanted to do was use a completely different font for italic, specifically a block font for the heading, with a fancy script font for the em text.

I assume I'm out of luck and cufon can't do something like this? I know it's a bit irregular, but it seemed like a potentially good way to recreate this designer's "vision" without having to export an image for each heading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use more than one font with Cufon.

Make your Cufon call like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('span.regular', { fontFamily: 'RegularFont' });
    Cufon.replace('span.bold', { fontFamily: 'BoldFont' });
</script>
```

Then use two span elements in your phrase, like so:

```
<span class="regular">This is <span class="bold">Cufon</span> using two fonts.</span>
```